# Adjusting padding of textarea with border radius

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to dynamically change `padding` of `textarea` when there is border radius involved? See text getting clipped in the fiddle below at corners of textarea.

http://jsfiddle.net/fNyHs/462/

idea is to get an oval text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".textfill.little").textfill();

    $(".textfill.much").textfill(0, 11);
   if($(".textfill").css("border-radius")=="120px")
   {
   $(".textfill").css("padding","20px");
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fNyHs/463/

Comment: I was looking for more like dynamic padding, as in the text would fit the div as an oval. Do you know if that is doable?